# Reading multiple files and putting them into a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a several files in a directory, and each file contains lines of data where each line is to be a separate element in a list. However, with multiple files I would like each file to be a list of their own within an overall list of lists.

So far, I have been able to read in all files in "my path", and separate each line into a separate element. But I have only managed to collapse them into one flat list. But my task is to output a list of lists based on separate files in the directory.

What I've tried:

```
lst=[]
for x in os.listdir("my path"):
    with open(os.path.join("my path", x)) as f:
        lst.append([x.strip() for x in f.read().split('\n')])
```

Edit: Looks like the code was OK, but the directory that I specified in "my path" was referencing a specific file and not the directory itself.

Comment: But your code *does* generate a list of lists

Comment: LGTM. You may want to check whether `os.path.join("my path", x)` is in fact a file and not a directory though.

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right it looks look "my path" was referencing a file in the directory and not the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

def data(folder_path):
    for p in filter(Path.is_file, Path(folder_path).iterdir()):
        with open(p) as f:
            yield [l.strip() for l in f]


print(list(data('my path')))
```